# Termcal prints the calculated days on the table border

Tags: tables, calendar, termcal

The termcal package works fine for two or more `\calday` entries. However, if there are six `\skipday` entries, than the calculated days on the table border. Here is a snapshot of the problem:

[image]

This example was produced with the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage{termcal}

\newcommand{\TRClass}{%
\skipday % Tuesday
\skipday % Tuesday
\skipday % Wednesday (no class)
\calday[Thursday]{\classday} % Thursday
\skipday % Friday 
\skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
}

\newcommand{\Holiday}[2]{%
\options{#1}{\noclassday}
\caltext{#1}{#2}
}

\begin{document}
\paragraph*{Lab Tentative Schedule for Electric Circuit Analysis:}
\begin{center}
\begin{calendar}{8/18/2014}{2} % Semester starts on 1/11/2010 and last for 16
                    % weeks, including finals week
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\TRClass
% schedule
\caltexton{1}{Lab briefing}
\caltextnext{2.2 Charge, Current, Voltage, and Power\\
2.3 Voltage and Current Sources\\
2.4 Ohm's Law}

\end{calendar}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Any help on this problem is more than welcome.

Oliver Faust

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

There is a spurious space in the definition of `\ca@doaday` in the file `termcal.sty`. You have to put a `%` like

```
\renewcommand\ca@doaday[1]{% %%<--- spurious space
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    %% a4 doesn't work here
\usepackage{termcal}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ca@doaday[1]{% %%<--- spurious space
   \hspace*{-1em}\hbox{\vrule depth \calboxdepth height 0pt width 0pt\vtop{%  note \hspace* in the begining
                                           %% Adjust as needed.
   #1%                                 %options specified by |\calday|
   \csname\curdate options\endcsname%  % options specified by date
   \ifclassday\csname C\theclassnum options\endcsname\fi%   by classnumber
   \hbox to \hsize{\calprintdate\hfill\ifclassday\calprintclass\fi}%
   \vspace{2pt}
      \begingroup
        \let\\=\ca@normbs
        \raggedright
        \sloppy
        \the\weeklytext\par
        \csname\curdate text\endcsname
        \ifclassday\csname C\theclassnum text\endcsname
                   \stepcounter{classnum}\fi
      \endgroup
   }}%
    \global\newmonthfalse
    \advancedate%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\TRClass}{%
\skipday % Tuesday
\skipday % Tuesday
\skipday % Wednesday (no class)
\calday[Thursday]{\classday} % Thursday
\skipday % Friday
\skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
}

\newcommand{\Holiday}[2]{%
\options{#1}{\noclassday}%
\caltext{#1}{#2}%
}%

\begin{document}
\paragraph*{Lab Tentative Schedule for Electric Circuit Analysis:}
\begin{center}
\begin{calendar}{8/18/2014}{2} % Semester starts on 1/11/2010 and last for 16
                    % weeks, including finals week
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{0.3in}
\TRClass
% schedule
\caltexton{1}{Lab briefing}%
\caltextnext{2.2 Charge, Current, Voltage, and Power\\
2.3 Voltage and Current Sources\\
2.4 Ohm's Law}
\end{calendar}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Harish, thank you. Your answer has solved my problem.

Comment: @OliverFaust Glad it helped. On this site, best way of saying thanks is to upvote and accept the answers that helped you. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for details. :)

Comment: To Harish Kumar there is a problem with your solution: \noclassday does not increment the date counter: In your example, if you replace `\skipday\skipday' with `\noclassday\noclassday' the second lab will be on the 19th of august. This problem was pointed out by one of colleagues: Hey your lab ends in October and not in December ...

Comment: @OliverFaust: Answer updated. :)

Comment: To Harish Kumar, I am humbled in the presence of greatness. Thank you very much for updating the answer.

Comment: @OliverFaust Thank you for the great words. Up voting the answer and accepting it are the conventional ways to convey thanks in this site. For clarity please refer to [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) :)

Answer (score 2):

There are three places where spurious spaces can be found in the code. Removing them solves the problem, and the negative `\hspace` in the accepted answer is not required. Here's a solution without that. (I've also adjusted the size of `\calboxdepth` to fit your three lines.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ca@doaday[1]{% <--- Spurious space removed here
\hbox{\vrule depth \calboxdepth height 0pt width 0pt\vtop{%  
   #1%                                 %options specified by |\calday|
   \csname\curdate options\endcsname%  % options specified by date
   \ifclassday\csname C\theclassnum options\endcsname\fi%   by classnumber
   \hbox to \hsize{\calprintdate\hfill\ifclassday\calprintclass\fi}%
   \vspace{2pt}
      \begingroup
        \let\\=\ca@normbs
        \raggedright
        \sloppy
        \the\weeklytext\par
        \csname\curdate text\endcsname%
        \ifclassday\csname C\theclassnum text\endcsname
                   \stepcounter{classnum}\fi
      \endgroup
   }}%
    \global\newmonthfalse
    \advancedate%
}%
\renewcommand\advancedate{\stepcounter{date}% <--- Spurious space removed here
    \ifnum\thedate>\monthlength\relax
       \addtocounter{date}{-\monthlength}\advancemonth\fi}

\renewcommand\advancemonth{%
   \global\newmonthtrue\stepcounter{month}% <-- another spurious space
   \ifnum\c@month>12
      \stepcounter{year}\setleap\setcounter{month}1\fi}
\makeatother%


\newcommand{\TRClass}{%
\skipday % Tuesday
\skipday % Tuesday
\skipday % Wednesday (no class)
\calday[Thursday]{\classday} % Thursday
\skipday % Friday 
\skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
}

\newcommand{\Holiday}[2]{%
\options{#1}{\noclassday}
\caltext{#1}{#2}
}

\begin{document}
\paragraph*{Lab Tentative Schedule for Electric Circuit Analysis:}
\begin{center}
\begin{calendar}{8/18/2014}{2} % Semester starts on 1/11/2010 and last for 16
                    % weeks, including finals week
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.6in}
\TRClass
% schedule
\caltexton{1}{Lab briefing}
\caltextnext{2.2 Charge, Current, Voltage, and Power\\
2.3 Voltage and Current Sources\\
2.4 Ohm's Law}

\end{calendar}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]