# Why are my termcal class numbers not properly aligned?

Tags: formatting, numbering, positioning, termcal

My class numbers are misaligned. Please see this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{termcal}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\calprintdate}{%
\ifnewmonth\framebox{\arabic{month}/\arabic{date}}%
\else\arabic{date}%
\fi}
\begin{calendar}{1/16/17}{5} % must be a monday
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\skipday
\skipday
\calday[Wednesday]{\classday}
\skipday\skipday\skipday\skipday
\end{calendar}
\end{document}
```

You can see the problem here along the left column:

[image: left column problem]

Does termcal have a problem with classes meeting once per week?

Comment: There was [a similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161758/82917). The solution offered there still fails for the third line, unless one adds a second column. I have no time right now to go into the code.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the spurious space identified in [Termcal prints the calculated days on the table border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161758/82917), there is another in the definition of `\advancemonth`, which explains why this happens for 1 February. The code below produces the following:

[image]

In the other referenced question, there was also an additional `\hspace*{-1em}` before the `\hbox` in the definition of `\ca@doaday` (first line). The purpose of that was to move everything to the left a bit, add it back in if you want that.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{termcal}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ca@doaday[1]{% %%<--- spurious space
\hbox{\vrule depth \calboxdepth height 0pt width 0pt\vtop{%  
   #1%                                 %options specified by |\calday|
   \csname\curdate options\endcsname%  % options specified by date
   \ifclassday\csname C\theclassnum options\endcsname\fi%   by classnumber
   \hbox to \hsize{\calprintdate\hfill\ifclassday\calprintclass\fi}%
   \vspace{2pt}
      \begingroup
        \let\\=\ca@normbs
        \raggedright
        \sloppy
        \the\weeklytext\par
        \csname\curdate text\endcsname
        \ifclassday\csname C\theclassnum text\endcsname
                   \stepcounter{classnum}\fi
      \endgroup
   }}%
    \global\newmonthfalse
    \advancedate%
}%

\renewcommand\advancemonth{%
   \global\newmonthtrue\stepcounter{month}% <-- another spurious space
   \ifnum\c@month>12
      \stepcounter{year}\setleap\setcounter{month}1\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{calendar}{1/16/17}{5} % must be a monday
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\skipday
\skipday
\calday[Wednesday]{\classday}
\skipday\skipday\skipday\skipday
\end{calendar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For more on end-of-line `%`, see the three questions about *Use of percent signs* referenced in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2429/586