# Termcal prints the class day on the table border depending on the class day

Tags: termcal

The more the class day approaches Friday, the more `termcal` package prints the class number to the right.

Here we have some pictures of what I meant above:

Monday,

[image]

Friday,

[image]

I've also observed the same behaviour regardless of the number of classes per week but, with two classes per week, the problem appears to be on the first column only. For instance, with Thursdays and Fridays, it looks like this

[image]

With three classes per week, it's appearance doesn't bothers me at all, though the problem is still there. Here, we have classes on Wednesday, Thursday and Friday.

[image]

What can be done to solve this question?

Here's a resumed version of the code I've used to produce the images shown on this thread.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{termcal}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% I've used this on my original file to alter the date format and color
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\monthname{
    \ifcase\c@month
        \or jan \or fev \or mar \or abr
        \or mai \or jun \or jul \or ago
        \or sep \or out \or nov \or dez
    \fi
}
\renewcommand\ordinaldate{
    \the\c@date\textsuperscript{o}
}
\renewcommand\calprintdate{
    \ifnewmonth
        \textcolor{purple}{\arabic{date}}/\arabic{month}
    \else
        \arabic{date}/\arabic{month}
    \fi
}
\makeatother

% Command for the class day corresponding to Friday
\newcommand{\Sex}{
    \skipday
    \skipday
    \skipday
    \skipday
    \calday[sex]{\classday} 
    \skipday\skipday
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{calendar}{8/18/2014}{2}
        \setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
        \Sex
        \caltexton{1}{Start class}
        \caltextnext{Another class}
    \end{calendar}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of showing just images of the output, please edit your question to show a minimal compilable document that shows the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'm right on my way Alan Munn.

Comment: But I think this is a bug in the class. See  [Termcal prints the calculated days on the table border](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/161758) and [Why are my termcal class numbers not properly aligned?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/369257).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Termcal prints the calculated days on the table border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161758/termcal-prints-the-calculated-days-on-the-table-border)

Comment: I've read the solution presented on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161758/termcal-prints-the-calculated-days-on-the-table-border and it doesn't work out of the box in the present situation. It pulls all of the text to the left including the class description, not just the class number.

Comment: The extra space you're getting is the result of the bug...so if you want it back you'll have to do it by editing the code. I've posted a solution. (And the linked duplicate is really a hack, since the negative `\hspace` shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked solution is a bit of a hack, and there are in fact (at least) three places in the class that require `%` to eliminate spurious spaces in the code. It is those spurious spaces that are moving your date and class text to the right.  So removing them will move all the text to the left, which is how the class is supposed to work. There was also a spurious space in your redefinition of `\printdate`, which I have also fixed.

### Removing spurious spaces

First, here are the necessary redefinitions to make the class work as designed, using your document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{termcal}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ca@doaday[1]{% Added here
\hbox{\vrule depth \calboxdepth height 0pt width 0pt\vtop{%  
   #1%                                 %options specified by |\calday|
   \csname\curdate options\endcsname%  % options specified by date
   \ifclassday\csname C\theclassnum options\endcsname\fi%   by classnumber
   \hbox to \hsize{\calprintdate\hfill\ifclassday\calprintclass\fi}%
   \vspace{2pt}
      \begingroup
        \let\\=\ca@normbs
        \raggedright
        \sloppy
        \the\weeklytext\par
        \csname\curdate text\endcsname%
        \ifclassday\csname C\theclassnum text\endcsname
                   \stepcounter{classnum}\fi
      \endgroup
   }}%
    \global\newmonthfalse
    \advancedate%
}%
\renewcommand\advancedate{\stepcounter{date}% Added here
    \ifnum\thedate>\monthlength\relax
       \addtocounter{date}{-\monthlength}\advancemonth\fi}

\renewcommand\advancemonth{%
   \global\newmonthtrue\stepcounter{month}% <-- another spurious space
   \ifnum\c@month>12
      \stepcounter{year}\setleap\setcounter{month}1\fi}

% I've used this on my original file to alter the date format and color
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\monthname{
    \ifcase\c@month
        \or jan \or fev \or mar \or abr
        \or mai \or jun \or jul \or ago
        \or sep \or out \or nov \or dez
    \fi
}
\renewcommand\ordinaldate{
    \the\c@date\textsuperscript{o}
}
\renewcommand\calprintdate{% Added here
    \ifnewmonth
        \textcolor{purple}{\arabic{date}}/\arabic{month}
    \else
        \arabic{date}/\arabic{month}
    \fi
}
\makeatother

% Command for the class day corresponding to Friday
\newcommand{\Sex}{
    \skipday
    \skipday
    \skipday
    \skipday
    \calday[sex]{\classday} 
    \skipday\skipday
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{calendar}{8/18/2014}{2}
        \setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
        \Sex
        \caltexton{1}{Start class}
        \caltextnext{Another class}
    \end{calendar}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of first code]

### Adding more space

If you want to indent the date and the class text more, then you need to add spacing to do that yourself, both in the definition of `\ca@doaday` and your redefinition of `\printdate`. To do this I've created a new length and added an appropriate `\hspace*` to insert the space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{termcal}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newlength{\tcalindent}
\setlength{\tcalindent}{1em}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ca@doaday[1]{% Added here
\hbox{\vrule depth \calboxdepth height 0pt width 0pt\vtop{%  
   #1%                                 %options specified by |\calday|
   \csname\curdate options\endcsname%  % options specified by date
   \ifclassday\csname C\theclassnum options\endcsname\fi%   by classnumber
   \hbox to \hsize{\calprintdate\hfill\ifclassday\calprintclass\fi}%
   \vspace{2pt}
      \begingroup
        \let\\=\ca@normbs
        \raggedright
        \sloppy
        \the\weeklytext\par
        \hspace*{\tcalindent}
        \csname\curdate text\endcsname%
        \ifclassday\csname C\theclassnum text\endcsname
                   \stepcounter{classnum}\fi
      \endgroup
   }}%
    \global\newmonthfalse
    \advancedate%
}%
\renewcommand\advancedate{\stepcounter{date}% Added here
    \ifnum\thedate>\monthlength\relax
       \addtocounter{date}{-\monthlength}\advancemonth\fi}

\renewcommand\advancemonth{%
   \global\newmonthtrue\stepcounter{month}% <-- another spurious space
   \ifnum\c@month>12
      \stepcounter{year}\setleap\setcounter{month}1\fi}

% I've used this on my original file to alter the date format and color

\renewcommand\monthname{
    \ifcase\c@month
        \or jan \or fev \or mar \or abr
        \or mai \or jun \or jul \or ago
        \or sep \or out \or nov \or dez
    \fi
}
\renewcommand\ordinaldate{
    \the\c@date\textsuperscript{o}
}
\renewcommand\calprintdate{% Added here
    \hspace*{\tcalindent}
    \ifnewmonth
        \textcolor{purple}{\arabic{date}}/\arabic{month}
    \else
        \arabic{date}/\arabic{month}
    \fi
}
\makeatother

% Command for the class day corresponding to Friday
\newcommand{\Sex}{
    \skipday
    \skipday
    \skipday
    \skipday
    \calday[sex]{\classday} 
    \skipday\skipday
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{calendar}{8/18/2014}{2}
        \setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
        \Sex
        \caltexton{1}{Start class}
        \caltextnext{Another class}
    \end{calendar}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of second code]